# What does 'transparent' mean in this book excerpt?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

There is an excerpt from a book concerned with operating systems:

> We have seen that operating systems have two main functions: providing
> abstractions to user programs and managing the computer’s resources.
> For the most part, the interaction between user programs and the
> operating system deals with the former; for example, creating,
> writing, reading, and deleting files. The resource-management part is
> largely **transparent** to the users and done automatically.

It is not clear to me why authors used the word *transparent* here. This word primary meaning is about a quality that enables to see through an object and notice things that otherwise obscured. But in fact, an operating system should do its best to *hide* dreadful intricacies of resource management from a user.

Perhaps *transparent* in this place implies an operating system provides a layer of abstraction which are easier to understand for a user (*transparent* has such figurative meaning: *simple, clear, and easy to understand*). But still in respect to OS it is all about concealing weeds, so is this word suitable in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with you that **transparent** is not the clearest word to use here, if you'll pardon the pun. But there is a similarity to **hidden**, which might have been a better choice: things that are transparent and things that are hidden are both impossible to see. So when authors say the resource management system is *transparent to the users* they mean *the users don't see it*.